# Stop Auto refresh Page when page contain specific text

Tags: javascript

I'm using violentmonkey, and this totally simple script for refresh page, but I'm kinda noob in this things.
I'm using this script for refresh one auction page, when I see newly listed item it take time when its purchasable, after some time when I'm refreshing page will appear "buy button".
Can anyone help me how make script to stop refreshing page when buy button appear?

```
var StRefTime = '0.25';  
if (StRefTime > 0) 
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",StRefTime*1000);
```

Comment: Keep track of buy button with a bool value. Add this bool value in if condition. Or simple when buy button appears set streftime to negative(if condition will fail automatically)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string to an integer.

Change `var StRefTime = '0.25';` to `var StRefTime = 0.25;`